# how to make set clickable false of recyclview cell

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am working on recycle view and want to disable click event at position, position get from api,

what i am trying :

```
     viewHolder. rl3_layout.setClickable(false);
     viewHolder. rl3_layout.setFocusable(false);
     viewHolder. rl3_layout.setEnabled(false);
```

but this is not working in my recyclview.

Comment: what is not working? post your full code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding in your `onBindViewHolder` an `onClickListener` on your `itemView` that does nothing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the option in the `OnBindViewHolder` and for each item.

```
 if(shouldBeClickable) 
 {
    viewHolder. rl3_layout.setClickable(true);
    viewHolder. rl3_layout.setFocusable(true);
    viewHolder. rl3_layout.setEnabled(true);
 }
 else
 {
    viewHolder. rl3_layout.setClickable(false);
    viewHolder. rl3_layout.setFocusable(false);
    viewHolder. rl3_layout.setEnabled(false);
 }
```